# Background image zoom-out effect

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to achieve an effect where the site loads with the background "zoomed-in". The background images should gradually zoom out after the document is ready.

I decided to use an absolute positioned element for my background:

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro_bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
   width: 100vh; height: 95vh;
}

.intro_bg {
    width: 140%;
    height: 140%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;

    background: url(../images/hills.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

jQuery :

```
    $('.intro_bg').animate({
        'width': '100%',
        'height': '100%'
    },20000, function() { alert(); });
```

Basically, this isn't working. It successfully scales `.intro_bg` but the image doesn't appear to zoom-out like intended. The image itself doesn't scale or move (which may be the whole point of `cover`).

**If my idea is just not going to work, what is the optimal solution to achieve a "background zoom-out" effect?**

Comment: The code seems ok, have you checked for JavaScript errors?

Comment: @Anton Yeah code works fine and no errors, but the issue is that it's only the size of '.intro_bg' that scales/morphs. The background-image itself, within that element, is always static (I think because it's set to `cover` ). Trying to set up a fiddle....

Comment: You need to use `cover`. Can you give us a LIVE example (or jsfiddle)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not change apply a transitioning class with a scale transform on timeout (to prevent immediate application)?

This has the additional advantage of maintaining a clear separation of concerns between functionality (JS) and presentation (CSS)

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ope432pL/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="intro">
    <div class="intro_bg"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.intro {
    width: 600px;
    height:600px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.intro_bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://www.picturesnew.com/media/images/image-background.jpg);
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:cover;
    transform:scale(1);
    transition:all 4s ease-in;
}
.intro_bg.zout {
    transform:scale(6); /* <--- change the scale of zoom out as appropriate */
}
```

Jq

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.intro_bg').addClass('zout');
},1000);
```

Comment: Your solution was perfect as a stand alone but I've just tried putting it on my site and noticed a problem when the page can scroll. You can see it live here: http://albarakadundee.co.uk/ The intro section is the second "bit". I'm a bit lost, was just wondering if you could take a quick look ?

Comment: @Juicy - you may want to apply `overflow:hidden` to `.intro`

Comment: Thanks, that does stop the overflow but there remains glitched "white patches" over some of the other images on the page.

Comment: The problem is with the fixed images, for some reason

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got stuck in my similar problem with an different mindset and your answer helps me to figure it out how to solved it. If you need a "Zoom in", you should use a scale(1) at your primary css rule and update to a higher value in your .zout, and if you need a "Zoom out effect" you use a value higher than 1 at your primary css rule to update it to 1 value at .zout class

Answer (score 1):

you can try to replace '%' with 'px'.

```
$('.intro_bg').animate({
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%'
},20000, function() { alert(); });
```

After:

```
$('.intro_bg').animate({
    'width': '100px',
    'height': '100px'
},20000, function() { alert(); });
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paydjo/g2ef7gc4/)**

Hope that work and helps

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/a2rokp6d/)**

css

```
.intro_bg {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```